# Separating the coordinates(3D coordinates) for each cluster in DBSCAN using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, dbscan

I was clustering some 3D coordinates using **DBSCAN** (using python). I was able to cluster it into different clusters. But now i want to separate the coordinates which belong to each of these clusters and print those coordinates into different text files. Can anybody please help me how to do it.

I have already tried to cluster into separate clusters and get the coordinates of each cluster. whole different codes will be also fine

I'm unable to post my codes due to some issue. But i will post the commands that i used to make my one. (This one is 2D)

```
from sklearn.cluster import DBSCAN
import numpy as np
data = np.random.rand(500,3)

db = DBSCAN(eps=0.12, min_samples=1).fit(data)
labels = db.labels_
from collections import Counter
Counter(labels)
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the result you want to achieve.

Comment: If the clusters like as follows .Counter({0: 34, 1: , 2: 25, 3: 10, -1: 3})
I want to get the coordinates for each of this points in each cluster.Ex:- for the 1st cluster (for “0” cluster), I want to print the coordinates of 34 points which belong to the 1st cluster in a separate text file like below.-32.143 12.990  -13.488/
-41.02  4.62  -15.68-34.21 13.61  -13.09/33.11 15.87  13.73/-26.49  0.16  -23.98/37.06  2.04  -15.55/-40.18  3.20  -15.02/39.40  3.04  15.67 /38.75  2.71  -15.41.I want print the coordinates of points belong to each cluster in text files.Can you please help me in this.

Comment: -32.760 14.072  -13.749
-37.100  1.953  -15.720
-32.143 12.990  -13.488
-41.077  4.651  -15.651
-34.219 13.611  -13.090
-33.117 15.875  -13.738
-26.494  0.165  -23.985
-37.069  2.042  -15.559
-40.187  3.209  -15.021
-39.407  3.043  -15.675 
-38.752  2.719  -15.411
Like this, I want print the coordinates of points belong to each cluster in seperate text files. @sentence please read the above comment also. Space was not enough to show the corrdiantes well. I want like this in separate text files for each cluster. Hope you got me

Comment: @sentence please let me know. If you didn't get my question

Comment: Let's see if I get it. You have a set of points, you cluster them, and you want to store them into files based on their cluster assignment. Is that right? If yes, what kind of file do you want to use? csv, txt, pkl?

Comment: yeah that's right. I want in a txt file. I want to store the coordinates of points,  for each cluster in a different txt files. means one file will contain the x,y,z coordinates belong to the first cluster. Next one will contain the coordinates of 2nd cluster. Like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store samples (`numpy.array`) in `.txt` files, you should first divide your samples in partitions based on cluster assignment and then save the resulting partitions.

```
from collections import defaultdict

clusters = defaultdict(list)

for i,c in enumerate(db.labels_):
    clusters[c].append(data[i])

for k,v in clusters.items():
    np.savetxt('cluster{}.txt'.format(k), v, delimiter=",", fmt='%s')
```

and you get 68 txt files, each one containing coordinates for one or multiple samples from your dataset.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. But I want to print something before the 3 coordinates. can I do it in this? I want, it to be print like this "ATOM  1    O   HOH X 1      -37.100  1.953  -15.720  1.00 43.38          O" like a PDB file in proteins.  If the 2 digits can increase with each line its great. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have posted a new question with the title "Separating the coordinates for each cluster in DBSCAN using python". can you please check it. Thanks